# Choose music you find pleasant, not incredible

Tags: word-choice

The following is part of the text I recently came across and have had trouble tracing to a valid, reliable source. Now, regardless of which source it comes from, could anyone please give me his/her opinion(s) on the writer's word choice in using "incredible," most probably as an idea which is meant to contrast with "pleasant"? I'd appreciate it if you put your opinions in clear and distinguishable terms as I need to decide whether to include the text in the book I'm trying to compile. Thanks.

*Studying with the TV or radio on adversely affects your ability to absorb what you're trying to learn. The same goes for any background music which competes for your attention. Choose music you find pleasant, not incredible.*

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because literary criticism is explicitly off-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To the best of my understanding of the author's meaning (which, I grant you, isn't quite clear):

Anything that sounds ***incredible*** will make you look up and think (in order to try and make sense of it, or to verify your initial impression, or ... etc).

Anything that sounds ***merely pleasant*** will NOT make you look up (and allow you to continue focusing on whatever you've been doing).

Therefore (according to the author, anyway), the former will distract you from whatever you're doing, while the latter won't.